# Saving Excel Sheet as PDF

Tags: excel, vba

Being an absolute VBA novice, I've pieced together some code that will run through an Excel sheet, checking everything's there, and then saving the sheet as a PDF file. I am, however, having some trouble with the saving part of the code. I keep getting the error "Compile error: Expected:=" to this line:

```
`Wsa.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type:=xlTypePDF,Filename:=myFile,Quality:=xlQualityStandard,IncludeDocProperties:=True,IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False)´
```

Am I just being a complete n00b here?

The whole thing looks like this:

```
Sub mcrSave()

Dim wsA As Worksheet

Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

'Check for mandatory fields
If Range("B3").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in applicant")
Exit Sub
If Range("C1").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in project title")
Exit Sub
If Range("H3").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in date of application")
Exit Sub
If Range("C5").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in expected cost")
Exit Sub
If Range("C7").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in time schedule")
Exit Sub
If Range("B10").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in project description")
Exit Sub
If Range("B18").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in potential benefits")
Exit Sub
If Range("B26").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in potential drawbacks")
Exit Sub
If Range("B34").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please fill in internal/external ressources")
Exit Sub



Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strPathFile, FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    Wsa.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type:=xlTypePDF,Filename:=myFile,Quality:=xlQualityStandard,IncludeDocProperties:=True,IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False)
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " & vbCrLf & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Export command to the following:

```
Wsa.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=myFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Also, you need to change your Mandatory field checks so each looks like:

```
If Range("B3").Value = "" Then
   MsgBox ("Please fill in applicant")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: This fixed the error message, but now when I run the macro, nothing at all happens.

Comment: Do you get the `PDF file has been created:` Msgbox appear?

Comment: No. Nothing happens at all.

Comment: Your mandatory fields checker isn't structured correctly. I'll alter my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error. The correct syntax is either

```
call Wsa.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type:=xlTypePDF,Filename:=myFile,...)
```

or

```
Wsa.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,Filename:=myFile,...
```